# How to get list of intermediate sums in a functional way? Using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

Given a list of objects i need to return a list consisting of the objects and the sum of a property of the objects for all objects in the list seen so far.

More generally given

```
var input = new int[] {1,2,3}
```

I would like to have the output of

```
// does not compile but did not want to include extra classes.
var output = { (1,1), (2,3), (3,6) };
```

What is the "right" functional way to do this?  I can do it in a standard iterative approach of course but I am looking for how this would be done in a functional, lazy way.

Thanks

Comment: A little more research on my part resulted in finding the haskell function "scanl1" which does exactly what I want.  An interesting project that implements many of these ideas in C# can be found at http://code.google.com/p/functional-dotnet/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in functional terms this is a combination of :

#### zip

take two sequences and create a sequence of tuples of the elements

and

#### map

Take a function `f` and a sequence and return a new sequence which is f(x) for each x in the original sequence

The zip is [trivial in c# 4.0](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx)
Taking the simplistic implementation from there we have

```
static class Enumerable 
{ 
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, 
        IEnumerable<TSecond> second, 
        Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> func) 
    { 
        var ie1 = first.GetEnumerator(); 
        var ie2 = second.GetEnumerator();

        while (ie1.MoveNext() && ie2.MoveNext()) 
            yield return func(ie1.Current, ie2.Current); 
    } 
}
```

We then need the map. We already have it, it's what we call Select in c#

```
IEnumerable<int> input = { 1,2,3,4 };
int a = 0;
var accumulate = input.Select(x => 
    {
         a += x; 
         return a;
    });
```

But it is safer to bake this into it's own method (no currying in c#) and allow support for arbitrary types/accumulations.

```
static class Enumerable 
{ 
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectAccumulate<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> seq,
        Func<T,T,T> accumulator) 
    { 
        var e = seq.GetEnumerator(); 
        T t = default(T);             
        while (e.MoveNext()) 
        {
            t = accumulator(t, e.Current);
            yield return t;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Then we can put them together like so

```
var input = new int[] {1,2,3};
var mapsum = input.Zip(
    input.SelectAccumulate((x,y) => x+y), 
    (a,b) => new {a,b});
```

This will iterate over the sequence twice, but is more general. You could choose to do the accumulator yourself within a standard select and a simple closure but it is no longer so useful as a 'building block' which is one of the driving forces behind functional programming.

Tuple support is a pain except within a method as the anonymous types don't traverse method boundaries without quite a bit of hassle. A few basic tuples should be included in c# 4.0. assuming a tuple class/struct called `Pair<T,U>` you could do:

```
public static IEnumerable<Pair<T,T>> ZipMapAccumulate<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> input,
    Func<T,T,T> accumulator)
{
    return input.Zip(
        input.SelectAccumulate((x,y) => accumulator (x,y)), 
        (a,b) => new Pair<T,T>(a,b));
}

//get an int specific one
public static Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<Pair<int,int>>> 
    ZipMapSum()
{
    return input => Enumerable.ZipMapAccumulate(
        input, 
        (i,j) => i + j);
}
```

Where c# linq becomes much more cumbersome than languages like f# is the poor support for operators, currying and tuples unless you keep everything inside one function and 'reconstruct it' each and every time for each type.

Comment: Nice.  I think this really gets me where I wanted to go.  Thanks

Comment: Nice and most functional solution. +1

Comment: cool - if any of the terms were confusing let me know and I'll try to hyper link to definitions/add more info...

Comment: If whoever gave the -1 would like to comment why, the code was written from memory so may have errors I should fix...

Comment: +1 from me, I liked your solution. I need to learn more about zip

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the shortest approach:

```
int sum = 0;
var result = input.Select(i => new { i, S = sum += i });
```

Comment: Yes, you can combine the assignment and the increment into one statement :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var output = input.Select((i, indexI) => 
    new {
           Element = i,
           RunningSum = input.Where((j, indexJ) => indexJ <= indexI).Sum()
        });
```

This will yield a collection of an anonymous type with the two properties Element and RunningSum.

**UPDTAE**

Here is another solution using just the LINQ Aggregate extension method. And yes, it is ugly.

```
var output = input.Aggregate(
   new List<KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>>(),
   (result, element) =>
   {
      result.Add(new KeyValuePair<Int32, Int32>(
         element,
         element + result.LastOrDefault().Value));
      return result;
   });
```

Comment: This will end up running the sum for each element in the list, which could be prohibitive on performance for a large list. as you will do the number of sums equal to the factorial of number of elements in the list.

Comment: Yes, it is not optimal, but I cannot think of an easy LINQ solution without calculating the sum for each element, because it would be a recursive definition. But it is not as bad as n! - just n².

Comment: Right.  I would to avoid this if at all possible.

Comment: My solution avoids that by the way. A lambda can have multiple statements so you just do the sum yourself.

Comment: +1: I do like this solution made me think of other ways to combine expressions. neat

Answer (score 2):

```
    int runningTotal=0;
    var p = input.Select((l)=>
        {
            runningTotal+=l;
            return new {l,Total=runningTotal};
        });
```

## Edit

Foreach will always be in order. Open up reflector and look at ForEach on the List (ForEach doesn't exist on an array) But all ForEach does is a for loop over the elements.

I'm not sure about the select, as far as I know it is but I've never dug into it.

Comment: Nice, I had not thought of the Select(1) => ...) but there is the problem of runningTotal being mutated by the query.  I think in my situation that is OK, but is that state mutation "OK" as a functional solution?

Comment: Our lambda is closing around the running total. Since this is the only place it is used I don't see why not. I'm sure there has to be a better way.

Comment: Is the order of execution in the .Select or .ForEach calls always guaranteed to be in order? If not, all these solutions could end up returning data in the wrong order, and some (the foreach) could end up with wrong data as well.

Comment: Functional programming is to a large extend about avoiding state. So I think it is not a good functional solution. And runningTotal is visible outside of the lambda function and could be manipulated from there yielding false results.

Comment: It could be manipulated if you allow it to be manipulated but there are plenty of solutions to resolve that. Create a function which has this in it, and then runningTotal is private to the function , and if this is the only responsability of the function, You should be safe from it mutating latter on.

Comment: @Gaijin42: the order the Select and ForEach methods use is the exact same order that the Enumerable returns its results in

Comment: @danbruc: I agree with your other point but if your list is large it might be worth the tradeoff.

Comment: I agree - it is very unlikly that this state will bring you into trouble. But to me it feels not right as a functional solution. It is just the 'standard iterative approach' wrapped in a single LINQ statement. There is nothing from the beauty of a recursive definition in a functional language.

Comment: Just to clearify. I am not defending my solution - it is really not something you want to do. Just want to state that this solution is not so functional. I am thinking about using a recursive extension method or something like that to hide the imperative part and make the code look functional.

Comment: @Danbruc: I like your solution, I know I agree with you but I've not come up with a good solution yet that can avoid the counter. I keep thinking that a recursive function like this should be feasible within the language today but perhaps not.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = new int[] {1,2,3}
var output = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>();
int runningTotal = 0;

foreach (int current in input)
{
  runningTotal += current;
  output.Add(new KeyValuePair(current, runningTotal);
}
```

It would be easy to convert this to the Linq .Foreach() function instead if you really want. the problem would be if you don't want a seperate running total.

the functional version :

```
intput.Foreach(current=>
{
    runningTotal += current;
      output.Add(new KeyValuePair(current, runningTotal);

}
);
```

Comment: Foreach isn't a linq query. It's part of List<T> introduced with anonymous delegates in .net 2.0. However it would be a functional approach

Answer (score 0):

Functional implementation (no side effects) and no extensions:

```
internal struct Tuple<T> {
    public T A;
    public T B;
}

internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var ints = new[] { 5, 7, 11, 13 };
        IEnumerable<Tuple<int>> result = ints.Aggregate<int, IEnumerable<Tuple<int>>>(new List<Tuple<int>>(),
                (sum, item) => sum.Concat(new[] { new Tuple<int> { A = sum.LastOrDefault().A + item, B = item } }));

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result.Select(item => "(" + item.A + "," + item.B + ")").ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Though can't figure out how to make it with anonymous type instead of Tuple.
Also could be simplified if there would be:

```
IEnumerable<T> Append(this IEnumerable<T> @this, T item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here it is in F#, using the built-in Seq.scan function:

```
> let input = [1;2;3];;

val input : int list

> input |> Seq.scan (fun (_, acc) x -> (x, acc + x)) (0,0) |> Seq.skip 1;;

val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(1, 1); (2, 3); (3, 6)]
```